# text error poping in jquery validation is not red

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

My problem is when i click the button some of the fields that has a jquery validation dont have a redish look in the text if error. And the selectbox for the birthday dont have a red border if error. Can anyone help me fix this?

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/17/

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/validation_zps7b476959.png.html

i tried this but they dont have the same color.

```
.help-block {
    color:#FF0000; 
}
```

Comment: The red color is `#a94442`. Try to use the developer tools.

Comment: Post enough code for a complete working example within your OP.  Pictures and demos are ok but they should only augment the actual code, not serve as replacement.

Comment: Don't use input-group and form-group on the same div. Place a new div with input-group inside the form-group. http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **[Updated Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/22/)**

The Date fields are select boxes, you have to explicity add a class to it. Check `select-class`.

**CSS :**

```
.help-block {
    color: #a94442;
}

.select-class{
    border: solid 1px #a94442;

}
```

**JS :**

```
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    $(element).addClass('select-class');                      

},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $(element).removeClass('select-class');   
},
```

Answer (score 2):

use this color:

```
.help-block {
    color: #a94442;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because some generated error messages were in out of form control group class so add
this css

```
.help-block {
    color:#AD4E4C; 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/18/)

Answer (score 0):

update your following code

```
 highlight: function (element) {
   $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
 },
 unhighlight: function (element) {
   $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
 }
```

To

```
 highlight: function (element) {
   $(element).closest('.form-group').parent().addClass('has-error');
 },
 unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').parent().removeClass('has-error');
 }
```

.help-block has red color only if it is children of .has_error class.

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/20/) for working code